# How can I unstick 2 objects glued with superglue?

Tags: adhesive

I have glued 2 cubes of plastic together (each one roughly as big as a thumb) but I didn't align them well. I would like to unstick them and stick them again. They are cubes so the surfaces are flat.

I have used superglue. How can I tear them apart ? I have seen lots of questions asking about how to get rid of extra superglue but not how to unglue

Thanks

Comment: I have used acetone to get residue off in the past. If the parts are well sealed you may be out of luck because the acetone can't get in the space between the parts to soften the glue but might be worth a try if the acetone dosent melt the plastic.

Comment: worked great. for info for whom may read this later, the cubes were in a black plastic that turned a little white. I don't care so much in this case but might be worth knowing

Comment: @EdBeal that's an answer!